# Does ivy-occur have a follow mode?

Tags: ivy

In `org-agenda`, it is possible to enable a "follow mode" so that moving the point over an agenda item automatically displays the linked item in another window.

In `ivy-occur`, you need to press `f` to get this, it doesn't happen automatically.

Is there a way to make `j` and `k` behave like `j f` and `k f`?

Comment: Though not identical, `n` (`next-error-no-select`) and `p` (`previous-error-no-select`) are close enough to `j f` and `k f`, respectively, for most of my uses. You can also enable `next-error-follow-minor-mode` by typing `C-c C-f` so that `j` and `k` behave like `n` and `p`, respectively. I'm not a big user of `ivy-occur`, though, so take these suggestions with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc:

```
c runs the command ivy-occur-toggle-calling (found in ivy-occur-grep-mode-map),
which is an interactive native compiled Lisp function in ‘ivy.el’.

It is bound to c.

(ivy-occur-toggle-calling)

Toggle ‘ivy-calling’.
```